# Is memcached necessary?

Tags: javascript, database, storage, memcached

I've recently used memcached and faced a question. Why we can't just use a dictionary from language instead of Memcached (e.g. Set() or Map() in javascript). Because in fact, Memcached is just a dictionary for temporary data. It seems to me that we violate the single responsibility principle but I don't understand how to form a fully correct answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using memcached or a language construct depends on what you are trying to solve and the context of your application.

If you can share memory using a language construct (like Set or Map) throughout the entire application and the amount of data to cache fits well within the limits of a single process, it's hard to justify the cost of doing a network call to fetch cache data + the overhead of maintaining a memcache server.

On the other hand, if you can't share memory throughout your entire application (e.g. imagine many servers / isolated processes), or the amount of data to cache is greater than what you'd like in a process, then using a cache server (like memcached) makes more sense.

These are not mutually exclusive, applications can leverage both (cache server + in-memory) to achieve multi-level cache. Check out [this](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2019/08/06/stack-overflow-how-we-do-app-caching/) post about how Stack Overflow does it.

The only case where I can see an application's local cache violating the SRP, is if it stores data unrelated to the application and makes it available to others.